# What generates these very slow postmeta queries?

Tags: database

I see a lot of such queries in "Sending Data" state, using SHOW PROCESSLIST.

Context is a high traffic Wordpress powered news site.

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE 
    `meta_key` = '_wp_attached_file' 
    AND LOWER(`meta_value`) IN 
        ('2016/06/file-1.jpg', 'A LONG LIST OF FILES HERE', ... ) LIMIT 76
```

So far, I have been unable to find what generates these queries. I tried searching for various parts of the query like '_wp_attached_file', 'post_meta' but found no places in the core where this would be generated, nor in my theme or plugins.

Comment: Some plugin or theme, I guess... It's not native WP query.

Comment: Any pointers on what would I be searching for? greping for "postmeta" in theme files doesn't seem to bring up anything interesting.

Comment: And in plugins? Searching for '_wp_attached_file' could be helpful.

Comment: Use the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin. It'll show you all the queries run for a request, how long they took, and - crucially - where they were made from.

Comment: Found it! It's the [Simple LIghtbox](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-lightbox/) plugin. Want to add your comment as an answer Jacob? Thank you very much.

Comment: I told you how to find the answer, not the answer itself. Answering your own question is allowed, so since you discovered the answer you should post it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a Lightbox plugin: [Simple Lightbox](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-lightbox/). I used another plugin: [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) to find it, as suggested in the comments by Jacob.